# How do I configure / manage Webmin crontab / cronjob views?

Tags: cron, webmin

How do I configure Webmin so the user can only see his crontabs, not all of the crontabs of the system?

- Webmin is installed with default options.
- crontab directory in webmin, cron module config: `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`

I added user access list in `/etc/webmin/webmin.acl` as `user1: cron` so the user can only manage the crontab module, but the user also sees other users crontabs.